# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'plot_coordinates'

Tags: python, plot

I would like to plot a graph using python showing variables on X/Y axis after applying MCA. I tried this code but returns the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'plot_coordinates'

This is the code:

```
ax = mca.plot_coordinates(
X=X,
ax=None,
figsize=(6, 6),
show_row_points=True,
row_points_size=10,
show_row_labels=False,
show_column_points=True,
column_points_size=30,
show_column_labels=False,
legend_n_cols=1)
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks,

Comment: What is `mca`? A `pandas.DataFrame` object? The error is accurate; [`pandas.DataFrame`  doesn't have an attribute `plot_coordinates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#constructor).

Comment: mca stands for multiple correspondence analysis. I have a dataframe named 'train' with many columns and I applied the mca on it using mca = mca.fit(train). This gives the principal components of the mca then I would like to plot the train variables on (x,y) graph while x is the 1st component and y is the second

Comment: It's always nice to provide a complete working example. In other cases, people are forced to guess. So, if we have to follow this route, what is the output of  `type(mca)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps but I ran into that same error. To fix it, I specified the X= to be the exact dataframe and columns/variables and it fixed the problem:
X=train[variables] instead of X=X

```
ax = mca.plot_coordinates(
X=train[variables],
ax=None,
figsize=(6, 6),
show_row_points=True,
row_points_size=10,
show_row_labels=False,
show_column_points=True,
column_points_size=30,
show_column_labels=False,
legend_n_cols=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mca = prince.MCA()
```

typeof mca is prince.mca.MCA ,it has the method .
if you add the code,

```
mca = mca.fit(X) # same as calling ca.fs_r(1)
mca = mca.transform(X)
```

type of mca is DataFrame.it do not have the method plot_coordinates.
The right code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import prince

X = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/balloons/adult+stretch.data')
X.columns = ['Color', 'Size', 'Action', 'Age', 'Inflated']

print(X.head())

mca = prince.MCA()

mca = mca.fit(X) # same as calling ca.fs_r(1)
mca1 = mca.transform(X) # same as calling ca.fs_r_sup(df_new) for *another* test set.
print(mca1)

ax = mca.plot_coordinates(
     X=X,
     ax=None,
     figsize=(6, 6),
     show_row_points=True,
     row_points_size=10,
     show_row_labels=False,
     show_column_points=True,
     column_points_size=30,
     show_column_labels=False,
     legend_n_cols=1
     )

ax.get_figure().savefig('./mca_coordinates.svg')
```